# typescript - can tsc be run against an entire folder?

Tags: typescript

I'm pretty surprised this isn't in the docs that I could find - but is there any way to just tell `tsc` to run against all files in a directory and its children without going through a whole `tsconfig.json` setup?

Comment: if you need to maintain the mirror structure of your *.ts files in the same directory structure, 
`tsc --rootDir .`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not that I know of.  Using `tsc` from the command line without a `tsconfig.json` requires that you specify each file individually, like so:

```
tsc MyFile1.ts MyFile2.ts MyFile3.ts
```

However, it looks like you can simply create an empty `tsconfig.json` (i.e. just `{}`) at the root of your TypeScript directory and it will do what you want. From https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json:

> If no `"files"` property is present in a `tsconfig.json`, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (*.ts or *.tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks! Omitting the `files` array in `tsconfig.json` did the trick.

Comment: Note that by _empty_ he meant a valid JSON file. i.e. at least `{}` should be there.

Answer (score 22):

You can use globs

```
tsc x/file1.ts x/file2.ts x/file3.ts
```

should be equivalent to

```
tsc x/*.ts
```

Comment: *note:* bash is what interprets the globs. note that MacOS has Bash version 3 by default, not Bash version 4, and that makes a difference in how globs are interpreted.

Answer (score 5):

If you have tsconfig.json file inside your project folder, you can directly type

> tsc  this command will compile all your ts files within the current folder, if you don't have tsconfig.json file, you can generate it by typing:'
>
> tsc -init

Answer (score 2):

This can be overkill, but I just wrote a PS function to use in VS Code as a task;

```
function CompileTypeScriptFiles($folder) {
    $tsFiles = Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "*ts" -Recurse
    $tsFiles | ForEach-Object {
        $tsFile = $_.FullName;
        $options = $tsFile + " --outDir js --sourceMap"
        Start-Process "tsc" $options 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows users need to use `for` loop:

```bsh
for %f in (./path/*.ts) do npx tsc "./path/%f" --lib es2018 --outDir ./path/bin
```

Don't forget to double `%` if using it inside of `bat` file:

```bsh
for %%f in (./path/*.ts) do npx tsc "./path/%%f" --lib es2018 --outDir ./path/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

I got around this on Linux/Mac by running:

```
pushd dir && tsc && popd
```

Looks like there needs to be a tsconfig.json file in the directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can build all files such as:

```
tsc ./**/*.ts
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, and unbelievable tsc cannot do this.